# Is the Foundational Model of Anatomy Ontology an Open Data that can incorporated in other Open Databases?

Tags: licensing, wikidata, biology

At the moment I'm investigating the state of anatomical knowledge on Wikipedia/Wikidata. I noticed that the Foundational Model of Anatomy has a lot of useful data and while the ID's are usually referenced in Wikipedia the other information isn't used.

They say on their website:

> The Foundational Model of Anatomy ontology (FMA) is OPEN SOURCE and available for general use.

But they also say:

> To obtain a copy of the FMA database either click the "Get the FMA" link to the left or see: FMA Licenses.

The link to FMA Licenses is a broken link.

Is the database supposed to be really open and could be incorporated in Wikidata, or is that something that's not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

The "FMA Licenses" link leads now to the [Express License Program](https://els.comotion.uw.edu/) page which says:

> Please contact license@uw.edu if you have any questions

I've emailed them and they've answered:

> The software is released open source – This info should answer your question, thanks for reaching out!
>
> http://si.washington.edu/content/accessing-fma-ontology
>
> > **Accessing the FMA Ontology**
> >
> > The Foundational Model of Anatomy ontology is available under a
> >     [Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported License](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/).
>
> Senior Manager, Innovation Development
>   CoMotion at University of Washington

The CC Attribution (CC-BY) license [meets](http://opendefinition.org/licenses/) the "Open Definition" criteria.

---

Unfortunately, incorporation via [federation](https://wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_federation_input) looks not possible: FMA's [Query Integrator](http://si.washington.edu/projects/qi) is not a real SPARQL endpoint (though allows SPARQL queries in some sense).

Probably one should link particular Wikidata properties to FMA properties using [wd:P1628](https://wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1628), [wd:P2235](https://wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P2235), [wd:P2236](https://wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P2236), and then interlink Wikidata entries that have FMA IDs using those FMA-linked  Wikidata properties.

---

P.S. It seems you will be interested in [WikiPathways](https://www.wikipathways.org/index.php/Help:WikiPathways_Sparql_queries).